# WooCommerce cookies and sessions - Get the current products in cart

Tags: javascript, wordpress, session, cookies, woocommerce

I try to learn the cookies of WooCommerce, for do any function operating by products the added to cart. I wrote in console `document.cookie`
And I get this data:

```
woocommerce_items_in_cart=1;
woocommerce_cart_hash=500d17f6c010b62b25c3f52893be945d;
```

I understand that the cookie "`woocommerce_cart_hash`" contains the products in cart, but I don't understand how to get the name of the product. What is it `500d17f6c010b62b25c3f52893be945d`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**Update** *(related to complicated @KMcAloon added answer)*

Get the session cookie and the cart from session, **in a simple way** *(indexed arrays)*:

```php
$session_cookie    = WC()->session->get_session_cookie();
$cart_from_session = WC()->session->get('cart');
```

---

**Original answer:**

As you will see below, **`woocommerce_cart_hash` doesn't contains the products in cart**, because there is a **third more complex cookie** related to **WooCommerce sessions DB table**.

The data **is not stored in the cookie herself** but in a corresponding reference located in DB WooCommerce session *(see below for details)*...

**Update:** For registered users, "persistent" cart data is also stored as user metadata *(see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77002943/how-to-remove-woocommerce-persistent-cart-data-from-database))*.

You have also to note that WordPress enable some local data storage.

> **The data below is taken from a real example case, where a non logged user add 2 products to cart.**

1. Woocommerce set 3 cookies when a non logged user add something to cart:

> - `woocommerce_cart_hash` => `44ffcb32800e5b20cfbb080753d48408`    *(security/integrity hash)*

- `woocommerce_items_in_cart` => `1` *(set to `1` when something is in cart)*
- `wp_woocommerce_session_3413758cad2ada414127ffee7347e40f` => `ac5f880c99503169574ad996f35f85c5%7C%7C1469492696%7C%7C1469489096%7C%7C17e565032403642121f5ad12cfa72c41` *(completely related to **`wp_woocommerce_sessions`** DB table created session at the same time than this cookie)*

2. And in DB table **`wp_woocommerce_sessions`** a session is generated at the same time:

> **`session_id`**       =>  `6` 
> **`session_key`**       =>  `ac5f880c99503169574ad996f35f85c5` 
> **`session_value`**     =>  `a:18:{s:4:"cart";s:600:"a:2:{s:32:"d82c8d1619ad8176d665453cfb2e55f0";a:9:{s:10:"product_id";i:53;s:12:"variation_id";i:0;s:9:"variation";a:0:{}s:8:"quantity";i:1;s:10:"line_total";d:35;s:8:"line_tax";i:0;s:13:"line_subtotal";i:35;s:17:"line_subtotal_tax";i:0;s:13:"line_tax_data";a:2:{s:5:"total";a:0:{}s:8:"subtotal";a:0:{}}}s:32:"a5bfc9e07964f8dddeb95fc584cd965d";a:9:{s:10:"product_id";i:37;s:12:"variation_id";i:0;s:9:"variation";a:0:{}s:8:"quantity";i:1;s:10:"line_total";d:18;s:8:"line_tax";i:0;s:13:"line_subtotal";i:18;s:17:"line_subtotal_tax";i:0;s:13:"line_tax_data";a:2:{s:5:"total";a:0:{}s:8:"subtotal";a:0:{}}}}";s:15:"applied_coupons";s:6:"a:0:{}";s:23:"coupon_discount_amounts";s:6:"a:0:{}";s:27:"coupon_discount_tax_amounts";s:6:"a:0:{}";s:21:"removed_cart_contents";s:6:"a:0:{}";s:19:"cart_contents_total";d:53;s:5:"total";d:53;s:8:"subtotal";i:53;s:15:"subtotal_ex_tax";i:53;s:9:"tax_total";i:0;s:5:"taxes";s:6:"a:0:{}";s:14:"shipping_taxes";s:6:"a:0:{}";s:13:"discount_cart";i:0;s:17:"discount_cart_tax";i:0;s:14:"shipping_total";N;s:18:"shipping_tax_total";i:0;s:9:"fee_total";i:0;s:4:"fees";s:6:"a:0:{}";}` 
> `session_expiry`    =>  `1469492696`

I can't explain all core processes (for that you will need to look in php core files). 
But if you look to `wp_woocommerce_session_…` **cookie value** you will see that you can cut it with `%7C%7C` substring, so we get here 4 substrings for this cookie value:

> - `ac5f880c99503169574ad996f35f85c5` (same reference that in the DB **`session_key`** and **`session_value`** of table **`wp_woocommerce_sessions`**).

- `1469492696` (the DB **`session_expiry`**  of table **`wp_woocommerce_sessions`**).
- `1469489096` *(same thing above)*.
- `17e565032403642121f5ad12cfa72c41` (??? - I don't really know what is this for…)

---

If the user come back and delete one item in his cart:

- **`woocommerce_cart_hash` cookie** value changes
- **`woocommerce_items_in_cart` cookie** value don't changes as an item remains in cart.
- **`wp_woocommerce_session_3413758cad2ada414127ffee7347e40f` cookie** value don't changes.
- **DB `wp_woocommerce_sessions` TABLE**, the **session ID `6`** has been **deleted/replaced** by a **new** generated **session ID** is that reflects the cart changes *(only one product)*.

---

> **So at this point you can see the relation between cookies and session DB table `wp_woocommerce_sessions` that contains all cart data related to non logged users** 
> *(in a ***`session_value` *serialized** multidimensional array or object)*.

> With [**Class WC_Cart**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html) you will be able to get this data. 
> You should also be able to use `WC()->cart` syntax in your php code…

> With [**Class WC_Session_Handler**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Session_Handler.html) you will be able to manipulate sessions herself.

> And to finish, [**Class WC_Ajax**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_AJAX.html) is used for cart changes.

---

References:

- [**Class WC_Cart**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html)
- [**Class WC_Session_Handler**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Session_Handler.html)
- [**Class WC_Ajax**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_AJAX.html)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer!

Comment: The last part of cookie "wp_woocommerce_session_.."  is the cookie hash.

Comment: All reference links are broken.

Answer (score 7):

Just to follow up on this in case anyone is interested. The selected answer is extremely helpful in breaking things down. The OP was asking how to get the products from the session cookies so I thought I would follow up.

Here is how I was able to extract the cart data from the `wc_woocommerce_session_` cookie:

```
  $session_id = null;
  $values = null;

  foreach( $_COOKIE as $key => $value ) {

    if( stripos( $key, 'wp_woocommerce_session_' ) === false ) {
      continue;
    }

    $values = explode( '||', $value );

  }

  $session_id = $values[0];
  $session = new WC_Session_Handler();
  $session_data = $session->get_session( $session_id );

  // Contains array of items in cart including product ids, quantities, totals, etc.
  $cart_data = unserialize( $session_data['cart'] );
```