# How to retrieve customer Woocommerce cart information at the local store or supermarket

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

How can I to retrieve customer Woocommerce cart information at the local store or supermarket.

The problem is most of my customers walk to my supermarket requesting to buy some same items they have in their cart. So I want a way to get a unique link to every cart and retrieve all cart information. Even if the user has not placed the order. Most my customers have uncompleted orders and later prefers to buy them manually at my shop.

Can I add serial numbers to every Cart and ask customers for it at my shop or supermarket?
How can I impremment that in Woocommerce

Comment: Thank you @LoicTheAztec. I have edited my question with more details. You can check now

Comment: All active cart sessions are stored in `wp_woocommerce_sessions` table, for logged or non logged users and are related to cookies. See this related answer: [WooCommerce cookies - Get the current products in cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38546354/woocommerce-cookies-get-the-current-products-in-cart/38547885#38547885)