# Getting the contents of a WooCommerce basket with JQuery

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've been working with WooCommerce recently and I was wondering if it was possible to get cart items via JavaScript or JQuery

I know you can use PHP functions to retrieve the contents of the cart but currently I do not have access to the backend of the site.

I've found a similar question here: [WooCommerce cookies and sessions - Get the current products in cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38546354/woocommerce-cookies-and-sessions-get-the-current-products-in-cart)

In the session there is a wc_fragment that contains the HTML of the cart.

```
{"div.widget_shopping_cart_content":"<div class=\"widget_shopping_cart_content\">\n\n\t<ul class=\"woocommerce-mini-cart cart_list product_list_widget \">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<li class=\"woocommerce-mini-cart-item mini_cart_item\">\n\t\t\t\t\t<a href=\"https://shop.co.uk/basket/?remove_item=5a48ab5b7a7d18cb26168d874821d031&#038;_wpnonce=3bccfbac25\" class=\"remove remove_from_cart_button\" aria-label=\"Remove this item\" data-product_id=\"12765\" data-cart_item_key=\"5a48ab5b7a7d18cb26168d874821d031\" data-product_sku=\"\">&times;</a>\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<a href=\"https://shop.co.uk/product/?attribute_pa_quantity=1-drink\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<img width=\"800\" height=\"450\" src=\"https://cdn2.co.uk/app/uploads/Overlapped-800x450.jpg\" class=\"attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail size-woocommerce_thumbnail\" alt=\"\" />Raspberry Drinking Yogurt - 1 drink\t\t\t\t\t\t</a>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<span class=\"quantity\">1 &times; <span class=\"woocommerce-Price-amount amount\"><span class=\"woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol\">&pound;</span>1.50</span></span>\t\t\t\t</li>\n\t\t\t\t\t</ul>\n\n\t<p class=\"woocommerce-mini-cart__total total\">\n\t\t<strong>Subtotal:</strong> <span class=\"woocommerce-Price-amount amount\"><span class=\"woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol\">&pound;</span>1.50</span>\t</p>\n\n\t\n\t<p class=\"woocommerce-mini-cart__buttons buttons\"><a href=\"https://shop.co.uk/basket/\" class=\"button wc-forward\">View basket</a><a href=\"https://shop.co.uk/checkout/\" class=\"button checkout wc-forward\">Checkout</a></p>\n\n\t\n\n</div>"}
```

Would it be possible to extract the elements from this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a solution for you. Maybe there is a better one but's how I would do it.

First create a custom JS file and register it. Also add a custom ajaxurl (in case you don't did this already):

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_enqueue_scripts_action' );
function wp_enqueue_scripts_action() {
    wp_register_script( 'child-theme', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/child.js', [ 'jquery' ] );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'child-theme' );

    wp_localize_script( 'child-theme', 'child_theme', [
            'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
        ]
    );
}
```

Now add an AJAX endpoint:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_cart_items', 'wp_ajax_get_cart_items_action' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_cart_items', 'wp_ajax_get_cart_items_action' );
function wp_ajax_get_cart_items_action() {
    $cart = WC()->cart;

    if ( $cart ) {
        wp_send_json_success( $cart->get_cart_contents() );
        /** @noinspection ForgottenDebugOutputInspection */
        wp_die();
    }
}
```

This will return the content of the cart in case a cart is available. Now call it inside your JS function. In my case for testing directly in the `document.ready` method:

```
(function ( $ ) {
    $( document ).ready( function () {
        let data = {
            action: 'get_cart_items'
        };

        $.post( child_theme.ajaxurl, data, function () {
        } ).done( function ( response ) {
            console.log( response );
        } ).fail( function ( response ) {
            console.log( 'Fail' );
        } );
    } );
})( jQuery );
```

This will return for example:

> 077e29b11be80ab57e1a2ecabb7da330: {key:
> "077e29b11be80ab57e1a2ecabb7da330", product_id: 249, variation_id: 0,
> variation: Array(0), quantity: 1, …}

I think you need to add some null checks but all in all its a working solution.