# How to get WooCommerce cart id?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have developed a Wordpress plugin which adds products programmatically using this code:

```
        WC()->cart->empty_cart();
        
        foreach ($productos as $producto) {
            WC()->cart->add_to_cart($producto->post_id, $cantidad);
        }
```

After I add products to cart I need to save the cart id, because after the user proceed to checkout and do the payment, I need to save the order id together with the cart id in a custom database table.

Any help, please?

On the other hand, in what database table are the carts and the orders stored?

EDIT (more details)

The actual problem is this. My plugin allows the customer to do some choices before proceeding with the purchase. All those choices are stored in a custom database table I created together with the default WordPress tables.

When the payment was made, I need to save the order id in that custom table in the same record of those choices, so that, in a later time, I will be able to know which choices were set for determined purchase.

Thinking in other way to accomplish this. The table record of choices has an ID (the primary key). Is it possible to save that ID together with the order? If that is possible, that way I can do the match between the order and the choices.

Comment: You mean this ? WC()->cart->get_cart_hash(); . Orders are posts you can find orders in default post table as in the woocommerce tables.  Depends what data you are looking for. As for carts they are stored as hash. That is cleared depending on how your store is setup. For example you can clear customer carts after leaving or keep em forever but if user clear his  cookies that data will be ketp at your side and lost for him so its up to the owner how he wants it.

Comment: @MartinMirchev Thanks Martin, yes, it is something like that. I have added more details in the question so that if you can advice which could be the best way to do that. Whether by mean of the cart hash or other better way.

Comment: In your case you dont need cart id since the the customer is sending you the order and this cart is deleted after. You can check this how you can access this data and keep it if you need that - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38546354/woocommerce-cookies-and-sessions-get-the-current-products-in-cart . Useful hooks would be woocommerce_new_order , woocommerce_add_cart_item_data . For both there are alot examples how to keep your data from there.

Comment: @MartinMirchev if I understand correctly, I can hook woocommerce_new_order. When hook is called, I can get the order id and save it in my custom table. When that hook is called? I guess it is called just after payment is completed if done by credit card. If  payment method is bank transfer, the order will be placed but in processing status, but the hook is also called, right? And, what hook should I use to detect when an order changes status? I did not find something like that in https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/hooks/hooks.html page.

Comment: You can check this article - https://rudrastyh.com/woocommerce/payment-complete-hooks.html . And yes woocommerce_new_order is called everytime when order is created. So from there you can save your data or if you want to save data only for specific status then check this article.

Comment: @MartinMirchev Hello... I have hooked and develop the code to accomplish what I need. However, there is something missing. I need to store some data in the session so that when the order is placed, I can know which records to update with the order id. I was searching for information about storing that data in sessions but I am lost with that. One attempt was to do something like this: $wp_session = WP_Session::get_instance();, but a class not found error is thrown. Can you show me how to use sessions in wordpress?

Comment: Lets move the conversation in chat room - https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247784/how-to-get-woocommerce-cart-id . Explain what kind of data you want to store with your order.

Comment: @MartinMirchev thanks... I have sent you a message in the chat, but finally I could do all I wanted. I used session object from WooCommerce to share data between the plugin and the order. I am saving product meta data for the administrator to be able to see that data in the order details, and I can also save a specific information in my custom database when the order changes status to complete. Regards.