# How to remove WooCommerce persistent cart data from database?

Tags: php, mysql, session, woocommerce, cart

From answers found in stack overflow, I noticed that WooCommerce cart data stored in `wp_woocommerce_sessions` database table, but after deleting data from this table and also deleting related cookies and session store in the browser, all items are still remaining in the cart.

How to remove WooCommerce persistent cart data from database?

Comment: If the table is empty, close the browser to clear the session most likely.

Comment: It didn't help, but thank you;-)

Comment: What about a full reboot?  If that doesn't work, then check every table, maybe there is another table it stores things like this.

Comment: It's too complicated way. Better to know what tables exactly store this data

Comment: And another strange thing — why question is disliked

Comment: I didn't do it, but if you read the terms of service, you NEED to post the code, the table layouts, and all that, otherwise its just a guessing game.  It creates brevity.

Comment: It's disliked and could be closed as duplicated, as your title was not reflecting what you really wanted to ask, and your content was a bit unclear.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Manually deleting rows from a table sounds strange, as no user of your website would be able to do this

Comment: @NicoHaase In WooCommerce users can empty themselves the cart by removing each item added previously. So this is just for the OP, for sure, his intention is not explained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For registered users, **persistent cart data** is stored as user metadata in `wp_usermeta` database table. You need also to remove that persistent cart user metadata **from the user ID**:

```php
update_user_meta( $user_id, '_woocommerce_persistent_cart_1', '' );
```

So the `meta_key` to target in `wp_usermeta` table is `_woocommerce_persistent_cart_1` **for the related User ID**.

The best way to remove the persistent cart data programmatically is using  the `WC_Cart` method `empty_cart()`, that will empty cart, removing that persistent cart data at the same time:

```php
if ( ! WC()->cart->is_empty() ) {
    WC()->cart->empty_cart();
}
```

Related: [WooCommerce cookies and sessions - Get the current products in cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38546354/woocommerce-cookies-and-sessions-get-the-current-products-in-cart/38547885#38547885)

Comment: Yes, this helped=) Thanks a lot! So to get an empty cart for registered user one should delete both wp_usermeta table and related wp_woocommerce_sessions table

Comment: I marked answer as accepted. Forgot to do this